# Copying a Directory to a Destination, if its not already present

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to copy a directory - C:/user/som to C:/admin/ only if the dir 'som' is not present in C:/admin/, using a batch file.
My batch file is like this-

```
SET Location= C:\admin
IF NOT EXIST "%Location%\som" xcopy "C:/user/som" "C:/admin/som" /S /E
```

This is not working properly, even if the dir- c:/admin/som is present it is asking me if I would like to overwrite the files in the Directory. What is going wrong here?

Adding to this- When I am doing the xcopy it is asking me if "C:\admin\som" is a File or a directory, and asking me to select F for File and D for Directory, now I want this to be automatically selected to be D, can that be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET "Location=C:\admin"
IF NOT EXIST "%Location%\som\." xcopy "C:\user\som" "C:\admin\som" /S /E
```

This should work.

Note: possibly not a requirement, but better practice:

set "var=string" will set `var` to `string`, omitting any trailing spaces on the line (if they exist). Including trailing spaces can cause chaos - and they're hard to spot. In your code, the leading space **is** included in the value assigned.

Note that `\` is a directory-separator; `/` is a switch. Conversion is sporadic.

Comment: `IF NOT EXIST "%Location%\som\"` <--- the trailing backslash is the key to detecting a folder reliably (as long as it is `not over a LAN`).  Your added period doesn't work correctly because it will fire on a file called `som`

Comment: When I am doing the xcopy it is asking me if "C:\admin\som" is a File or a directory, and asking me to select F for File and D for Directory, now I want this to be automatically selected to be D, can that be done.

Comment: use `"C:\admin\som\"` with the trailing backslash on the target folder

Comment: Or append switch `/I`, see documentation of [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx).